# Python ARIMA model - missing values after differencing the data

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I am using ARIMA model in python to make time-series prediction. After analyzing the data, I noticed that the data was seasonal and had a trend. To ensure my assumptions, I ran the ADFuller test and indeed the data is not stationary.

To make the data stationary, I differenced the data once and plotted it. Then, I tried to ran the ADFuller test again but I get the following error:

MissingDataError: exog contains inf or nans

That's the code for ADFuller test:

```
result = adfuller(df['power'])
print(result)
```

Does differencing the data create missing values? I do not have any missing values in the original data. I only get this error after differencing the data. I really do not understand what's going on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you differencing the data? Usually a `df.diff()` operation will insert a row of NaN at the beginning so the resulting dataframe has the same shape. See the example in the pandas docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html

Comment: @alkasm thanks for the comment. It solved the problem. dff = df.diff().dropna()

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.diff().dropna()` when you are using adf test again once more, the code will be `result = adfuller(df['power'].dropna())` if `df['power']` is already differenced.